# SwipeView BottomItems breaking TapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a SwipeView which contains a 2x2 Grid. Each row of the grid has a BoxView with a TapGestureRecognizer. If my SwipeView has SwipeView.TopItems, SwipeView.LeftItems, or SwipeView.RightItems, then everything works fine, but if I have SwipeView.BottomItems, then my TapGestureRecognizers don't fire.

Here is my PlayerLifeView.xaml:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="SampleApp.Views.PlayerLifeView"
             x:Name="PlayerLifeContentView">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <SwipeView x:Name="PlayerLifeSwipeView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <SwipeView.BottomItems>
                <SwipeItems>
                    <SwipeItemView x:Name="PlayerLifeSwipeItemView">
                        <yummy:PancakeView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                            <Label x:Name="HiddenViewLabel" Text="Test Text" TextColor="DarkMagenta" FontSize="40" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                        </yummy:PancakeView>
                    </SwipeItemView>
                </SwipeItems>
            </SwipeView.BottomItems>
            <yummy:PancakeView CornerRadius="30,30,30,30">
                <Grid x:Name="PlayerLifeGrid" ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label x:Name="LifeTotalLabel"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.Row="0" 
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                        FontSize="120"
                        TextColor="White"/>
                    <BoxView 
                        x:Name="DecrementBox"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Opacity="0">
                        <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="DecrementTapGestureRecognizer" Command="{Binding DecrementValCommand}" />
                        </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                    </BoxView>
                    <BoxView
                        x:Name="IncrementBox"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                        Opacity="0">
                        <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="IncrementTapGestureRecognizer" Command="{Binding IncrementValCommand}" />
                        </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
                    </BoxView>
                </Grid>
            </yummy:PancakeView>

        </SwipeView>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Is this a bug? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I have tested in `4.8.0.1451` of xamarin forms, it works. Could you share the version of Xamarin Forms used in your project?

Comment: Hmm I'm also using v4.8.0.1451 of Xamarin.Forms, v1.5.3.2 of Xamarin.Essentials, v2.0.3 of NETStandard.Library. The phone I'm using to test running Android version 9.

Comment: Okey, it's strange. It works in my project with `<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />`, you also can check whether this works.

Comment: Just wanted to return to say that I ended up scrapping the SwipeView and I'm using a PanGesture to produce the swipe I want. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Okey, glad you found the solution. You could update it in answer, then other people will know how to solve the same problem. In addition, you could submit it as an issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose) in Github. Then we can follow it up there to see whehter there will be some good ideas.